# Scanner Input not working when methods are called

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm relatively new to this and any help would be great.  For my homework I'm supposed to make a Triangle and a TriangleTester class that manipulates values inputed using scanner to find the length of a triangles sides, angles, perimeter, etc.  I'm not asking you to do my homework but maybe point me in the right direction.  This is just a small part but it keeps me from continuing.

What I can't figure out is how to get the variables that I input move across methods (if that makes sense.

Here's my Triangle code:

```
import java.math.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Triangle
{
private double A, B, C, D, h;
public double x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3;
public double lengthA, lengthB, lengthC;
private double angleA, angleB, angleC;
private double calcPerimeter, calcArea, getHeight;

//Create new Triangle
public Triangle(){
}

//to get length of a (AB) use A = (x1, y1) & B = (x2,y2)
public double getLengthC(){
double distance = Math.sqrt((Math.pow((x1-x2),2))+(Math.pow((y1-y2),2)));
return distance;
}
}
```

Here is my TriangleTester code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TriangleTester
{
public static void main(String[]args)
{
Triangle triangle1 = new Triangle();

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter x1 for point A");
double x1 = scan.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Enter y1 for point A");
double y1 = scan.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Enter x2 for point A");
double x2 = scan.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Enter y2 for point A");
double y2 = scan.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Enter x3 for point A");
double x3 = scan.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Enter y3 for point A");
double y3 = scan.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Set up a Triangle with coordinates " +"("+x1+","+y1+")"+ ","+ "("+x2+","+y2+")" +","+ "("+x3+","+y3+")");

System.out.println("Length of side c " + triangle1.getLengthC());
}
}
```

For testing purposes I would like to input the values:

```
0
0
4
0
3
3
```

and have the length of side c calculate to a 4.  I see that when I use the variable within my TriangleTester class the variables work, but when I call a method from my Triangle class the values don't work.

From where I'm at I would think I have to manipulate the triangle class so that my inputs from scanner are moved into that area....or I could be wrong

```
public Triangle(){} //I would have to add something here maybe?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you're right. Since you're getting the user input in the `TriangleTester` you need to pass them to the `Triangle` class.

```
public Triangle(double x1, double x2, double x3, double y1, double y2, double y3) {
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.x3 = x3;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.y2 = y2;
    this.y3 = y3;
}
```

And create the `Triangle` object after getting the values from user like this:

```
Triangle triangle1 = new Triangle(x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3);
System.out.println("Length of side c " + triangle1.getLengthC());
```

*Note:*  It is a recommended practice to make all the instance variables of your class as `private` and provide proper *getters and setters* for them.

Comment: ~I just have one little problem now.  So I've written everything as stated, but when I declare the parameters in my Triangle class as double, I get an error on the Triangle triangle1 = new Triangle(x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3); line  I did place it below the scanner. (I'm guessing since x1 isn't a double). Is there another thing I would have to do to to the x1...y3.  Do i have to add more somewhere? Like gets and sets in the post below by Luiggi?

Comment: @user3386695 - You've already marked an answer as accepted. If your problem isn't solved yet, why would you do that? And regarding your question, what is the error you're getting? And you can either use the way I suggested or others did. It is upto you. Just that in the way I said you won't have to call setter methods for each and every element. Everything is taken care by the constructor.

Comment: After changing things so that the Triangle class has the code above, and the object is moved below the all the scanner code i get the error :::TriangleTester.java:22:cannot find symbol...symbol:constructor Triangle(double, double, double, double, double, double) location: class Triangle. Then it shows the creation of the new object with a ^ under new (using JGrasp) ~~sorry I just joined the site~~

Answer (score 0):

The problem **is not** in the `Scanner`. You never fill the fields in your `Triangle triangle1` variable, so all the fields have their default value, which is 0.0.

Just start filling your fields from your variables. For example:

```
triangle1.x1 = x1;
//and on...
```

But this is a bad practice, it would be better declaring the fields as `private` and using setters for the job, or having a constructor that accepts the necessary fields.

```
class Triangle {
    private double x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3;
    public double getX1() {
        return this.x1;
    }
    public void setX1(double x1) {
        this.x1 = x1;
    }
    //other fields, getters and setters...
}

//...
//in your TriangleTester#main method
triangle1.setX1(x1);
//same for other fields...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the values of your `triangle` with the the values that you have read from the `Scanner`

This can be done as part of the constructor:

```
public Triangle (double x1, double x2, double x3, double y1, double y2, double y3) {
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.x3 = x3;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.y2 = y2;
    this.y3 = y3;
}
```

or you can set up setter methods on your Traingle class

```
void setX1 (double x1) 
{
    this.x1 = x1;
}

etc.
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class MainClass {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter x1 for point A");
    double x1 = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter y1 for point A");
    double y1 = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter x2 for point A");
    double x2 = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter y2 for point A");
    double y2 = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter x3 for point A");
    double x3 = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter y3 for point A");
    double y3 = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Set up a Triangle with coordinates " +"("+x1+","+y1+")"+ ","+ "("+x2+","+y2+")" +","+ "("+x3+","+y3+")");

    Triangle triangle1 = new Triangle(x1,x2,y1,y2,x3,y3);
    System.out.println("Length of side c " + triangle1.getLengthC());

}
```

}

and

```
import java.math.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Triangle
{
private double A, B, C, D, h;
public double x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3;
public double lengthA, lengthB, lengthC;
private double angleA, angleB, angleC;
private double calcPerimeter, calcArea, getHeight;

//Create new Triangle
public Triangle(double x1,double x2,double y1,double y2,double x3, double y3){
    this.x1=x1;
    this.y1=y1;
    this.x2=x2;
    this.y2=y2;
    this.x3=x3;
    this.y3=y3;
}

//to get length of a (AB) use A = (x1, y1) & B = (x2,y2)
public double getLengthC(){
double distance = Math.sqrt((Math.pow((x1-x2),2))+(Math.pow((y1-y2),2)));
System.out.println(distance);
return distance;
}
}
```

Comment: One time creation of scanner object is sufficient.

Comment: Sorry Everyone. Just read the question heading and guessed that might be the reason!!